# Suggestion on how I can clean up my code

Tags: c++

I have a project on object detection that will draw the results and the ground truth on the 2D image and 3D point cloud depending on user input. The user input is

Detection2D,GroundTruth2D,Detection3D,GroundTruth3D

For example an input of 1111 will draw detection and ground truth on both 2D and 3D while 1000 draws detection only on 2D

Therefore in my program, i have 4 big if blocks for the 4 conditions and 1 more for the final step. Is there anyway I can make my code look neater ? I have read another thread where the solution was to identify repetition in if else blocks. I have no repetition so are there any other ways ?

Comment: Use functions ?

Comment: Functions and a flag enum.

Comment: You mean you want condition based on the numbers. right? 
(i.e. 3 conditions for 111?)

Comment: Yeah that is true, so I will have a total of 4 conditions (4 ifs) for the 4 options.

Comment: Asking for suggestions as to how you can clean up code you haven't posted doesn't actually make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

A classic case of handling this is making a class per case inherited from a common base class.  Then a factory can create the right class based on the input.

However, with the given information it is unclear whether this approach will help or just complicate the code.

The main advantage could be a better split up of responsibilities and cleaner code at the caller side.

Here is an [example of a factory in wikipedia (java)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming))